# Leading slash in URL with htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I am currently trying to build a routing-script in PHP, where I am using htaccess to send URL-data to a PHP page.

My problem is, that I'm allowing all characters, which now means, that all URLs can have an unknown number of leading slashes.

My Htaccess is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This means, that this URL:

```
http://www.domain.com/sometext
```

Will give me the same $_GET['url'] as:

```
http://www.domain.com////////sometext
```

The requirements to my htaccess is, that I can actually use slashes in the string, BUT not in front :)

Does anyone know, what I am doing wrong? :)

### UPDATE

In my root folder, I have this htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteRule ^$    public/    [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) public/$1    [L]
 </IfModule>
```

And the in my /public folder, I have this htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+([^\?\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a URL like this:

```
http://www.domain.com////////sometext
```

The URI gets canonicalized before it's put through the regex in a `RewriteRule`. This means the URI gets turned into:

```
sometext
```

That means that the `url` parameter (i.e. `$_GET['url']`) should never have a ton of slashes in the front of the string. If this is a matter of seeing a ton of slashes in the browser's URL location bar, then you can do something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /{2,}([^\?\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

to get rid of the slashes in front.

Comment: How should this be implemented in the above .htaccess file to work? :)

Comment: It seems do do the trick, but now the $_GET['url'] return the WHOLE URL.. Where it is supposed to return "sometext" it now returns "http:// www. domain.com/sometext"... Why is that? :) (sorry for the space in the link, but else the comment field would treat it as a link)

Comment: @denlau The URI that `^(.*)$` matches in your rule will never have the scheme and hostname in it. No idea how that ended up in there, based on your rule, it is impossible.

Comment: I have updated my question with the two EXACT htaccess files, I am using right now. Does it make sense? :)

Comment: @denlau You're missing the `L` flag that was part of my answer

Comment: The it doesn't find anything - says that the browser can't find the page.. Hmm.. Without the L it returns "http:// www. domain.com/sometext" :)

Comment: @denlau Actually, try changing the `+` in the pattern to `{2,}`